# How do i send array values from angular controller to node and using that array values i have to search result from mongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am sending array values from angular controller to node, that is look like following [ '5732c95d599bfcc031013929', '5732c8e6599bfcc031013925' ] using this value i have to search result that matches both id in mongoDB. So i don't know how to write query for this.

### controller.js

```
$http({
            url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/manage-product',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {userId:vm.uid, code:vm.purchased, code1:vm.contributed}
        }).success(function(res) {
            //$scope.productlist = res;
            vm.result = res.result;
            console.log(vm.result);
            vm.count=vm.result.length;
            //console.log(vm.count + "New")

            vm.showPurchaserInfo = false;
            vm.showMessage = false;

            vm.info=[];
            vm.info[0]=vm.result[0]._id;
            vm.info[1]=vm.result[1]._id;

            if($scope.selectedCode == 2 || 3){
                if(vm.count >= 1 ){
                    $http({
                        url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/purchaserInfo',
                        method: 'GET',
                        params: {"proID" : vm.info}
                    }).success(function(res) {
                        vm.purchasedPeople = res.result;
                        console.log(vm.purchasedPeople);

                        if($scope.selectedCode == 2){
                            vm.showPurchaserInfo = true;
                        } else {
                            vm.showPurchaserInfo = false;
                        }
                    }, function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert('here');
                    });
                } else {
                    vm.result = res.result;
                    vm.count=vm.result.length;
                    console.log(vm.count);
                    if(vm.count == 0){
                        vm.showMessage = true;
                    } else {
                        vm.result=res.result;   
                        vm.showMessage = false; 
                    }
                }
            }
            //console.log(vm.result);
            //vm.docs=res.docs;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('here');
        });
    };
```

In the above code i am sending params of proID contains [ '5732c95d599bfcc031013929', '5732c8e6599bfcc031013925' ] this value to node.

### node.js

```
router.get('/purchaserInfo',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.query.proID);
    var pId = req.query.proID;
    var findPurchaserInfo = function(db, callback) {
        var cursor =db.collection('purchased').find({purchasedItemID:pId}).toArray(function(err, docs){
            if(err){  
                callback(new Error("Some problem"));
            }else{
                callback(null,docs);
            } 
        });
    };

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        findPurchaserInfo(db, function(err,docs) {
            db.close();
            if(err) return res.json({result:null})
            else
            return res.json({result: docs});
        });
    });     
});
```

In this node the value pId contains that array i had sent from angular controller. In the query it takes only first value of array and throw the result of that, but second one is not using.

mongoDb collection is look like following.

`{
   "_id": ObjectId("5733397f3e102e40365bb5de"),
   "quantity": "1",
   "store": "amazon",
   "purchasedPerson": "Admin",
   "email": "admin@gmail.com",
   "message": "I purchased this item for you",
   "terms": "yes",
   "purchasedItemID": "5732c95d599bfcc031013929",
   "purchasedDate": "2016-05-11T13:53:45.606Z",
   "ownerId": "56fe44836ce2226431f5388f" 
}`

and

`{
   "_id": ObjectId("5733006ace25b9682abb7c89"),
   "quantity": "1",
   "store": "amazon",
   "purchasedPerson": "vinay",
   "email": "vinay@gmail.com",
   "message": "I purchased this item for you",
   "terms": "yes",
   "purchasedItemID": "5732c8e6599bfcc031013925",
   "purchasedDate": "2016-05-11T09:50:17.718Z",
   "ownerId": "56fe44836ce2226431f5388f" 
}`

[screenshot after $in operator use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amgC5.jpg)

### from.html

```
<md-content  >  
<div class="md-padding"  layout="row"  layout-wrap >
    <md-card  ng-repeat="product in vm.result | filter:searchText" flex="40">
        <md-card-header>
            <md-card-header-text>
                <span class="md-title">{{ product.Product_Name }}</span>
            </md-card-header-text>
        </md-card-header>
        <img ng-src="{{ product.Image }}" class="md-card-image" alt="Image here">
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Brand:</span>  {{ product.Brand }}</span>
                <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Price: </span>  {{ product.Price }}</span>
                <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Capasity/Color:</span>  {{ product.Color }}</span>
                <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Url: </span>  <a href="{{ product.Url }}" target="_blank" >{{ product.Url | characters:100}}</a></span>
                <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Category: </span>  {{ product.Category }}</span>
                <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Description: </span>  {{ product.Description | characters:100}}</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>

        <div class="" ng-repeat="info in vm.purchasedPeople" ng-show="vm.showPurchaserInfo">
            <span layout="row"><hr flex/></span>
            <md-card-title >
                <md-card-title-text >
                    <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Purchased By:</span> {{info.purchasedPerson}} </span>
                    <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Store:</span> {{info.store}} </span>
                    <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Purchased Date:</span> {{info.purchasedDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}} </span>
                    <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Guest's Note:</span> {{info.message}} </span>
                    <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Purchase Quantity:</span> {{info.quantity}} </span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>
        </div>

        <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
            <md-button class="send-button md-accent md-raised" ng-click="vm.editDialog($index,product._id)">Edit</md-button>
            <md-button name="ProductId" class="send-button md-accent md-raised" ng-click="remove(product._id,'{{$index}}')">Remove</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
      </md-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)  operator in `find` like this

```
db.collection('purchased').find({purchasedItemId:{$in: pId}}).toArray(...);
```

**Edit** after comments

```
$http({
    url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/purchaserInfo',
    method: 'GET',
    params: { "proID": vm.info }
}).success(function(res) {
    var purchasedPeople = res.result;

    // iterate over people who purchased from currently logged in user (owner)
    for (var i = 0; i < purchasedPeople.length; i++) { 

        // iterate over owner's products       
        for (var j = 0; j < vm.result.length; j++) {

            // if vm.result[j].purchasedPeople doesn't exist create it otherwise use previously created      
            vm.result[j].purchasedPeople = vm.result[j].purchasedPeople || [];

            // if purchasedItemID is same as product id then add this person to this product
            if(purchasedPeople[i].purchasedItemID === vm.result[j]._id) vm.result[j].purchasedPeople.push(purchasedPeople[i]);

        }

    }

    if ($scope.selectedCode == 2) {
        vm.showPurchaserInfo = true;
    } else {
        vm.showPurchaserInfo = false;
    }
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert('here');
});
```

Comment: Actually i want to show like one product purchased by one person but when i use $in operator it shows all purchased persons to that particular product. That screenshot i have added to my question please see that.

Comment: Do you want to show one or all products for one person? If all for one person(by email for example) then add $and operator `{$and: [{purchasedItemId:{$in: pId}},{'email:'vinay@gmail.com'}]}`

Comment: No not like that, the first product is purchased by Admin and second one is purchased by Vinay, but it shows 2 people for single product. First product shows only Admin and second one shows only Vinay like that i want to do.

Comment: So you should query DB by some userId or email. Why you are sending to server array of purchasedItemId?

Comment: But the product collection doesn't contain userId or email, it contains only productId(purchasedItemId in purchased collection) and ownerId(logged in person Id)

Comment: Is the ownerId id of user who purchased the item?

Comment: no, ownerId(loggedIn user) has the products and some other people purchased his products. When user loggedIn and send the request of 'purchased items' then it shows who the people purchased his products.

Comment: Dropdown contains two options 'available items' and 'purchased items'. In 'available items' it shows only still not purchased items and in 'purchased items' it shows purchased items and who purchased that item.

Comment: OK so my answer is correct for getting all products by prodID array then all you need is on the  client in angular to append correct purchaser to the product they brought. Well for that you need to show the html code where you render the items.

Comment: It all make sense now :) so the best could be after you get purchasedPeople use for loop to add people by product ID to the product so that you get something like vm.result[x].purchasedPeople[x].purchasedPerson then you would change ng-repeat="info in vm.purchasedPeople" to ng-repeat="info in product.purchasedPeople" I'm on the phone so can't write more code now but if you need more help I'll look at it later.

Comment: I am not getting please help me

Comment: This `<md-card  ng-repeat="product in vm.result | filter:searchText" flex="40">` is ok but the other ng-repeat `ng-repeat="info in vm.purchasedPeople"` needs to look like this `ng-repeat="info in product.purchasedPeople"`